# Перевод экспоненциальной записи числа в "обычную"

Tags: javascript

Получаю данные в формате JSON. Некоторые числа отдаются в таком виде: `9.8e-7`.
Их нужно вывести на страницу в привычном для пользователя виде: `0.00000097`.
Как проще всего преобразовать такие числа?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Взял [тут (enSO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719775/parsing-and-converting-exponential-values-to-decimal-in-javascript):

```js
Number.prototype.noExponents = function() {
  var data = String(this).split(/[eE]/);
  if (data.length == 1) return data[0];

  var z = '',
    sign = this < 0 ? '-' : '',
    str = data[0].replace('.', ''),
    mag = Number(data[1]) + 1;

  if (mag < 0) {
    z = sign + '0.';
    while (mag++) z += '0';
    return z + str.replace(/^\-/, '');
  }
  mag -= str.length;
  while (mag--) z += '0';
  return str + z;
}
var n = 9.8e-12;
console.log(n.noExponents());
```

Answer (score 8):

[float.toFixed(len)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```
(9.8e-7).toFixed(10) // 0.0000009800
```

Comment: хорошо бы верно оценить длину числа и убрать лишние нули в конце.

Comment: `(9.8e-7).toFixed(10).replace(/\.?0+$/,'')`